# Creating hover messages with tool tip won't yield the same result for multiple hover messages

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create hover messages for each field that the user needs to fill out. The first hover message is centered how I want it, but when i try to create the same effect for the next field, the hover message is displayed in the wrong position. I'm not sure what I need to change in the CSS to get the same effect for all messages. 
[image]

I've tried changing the position, but it didn't help, not sure what else is relevant to this issue.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -35px;
  left: -295%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%; /* To the right of the tooltip */
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className="tooltip" style={{ "fontSize": "12px", "fontWeight": "bold" }}> Hello
<span className="tooltiptext"> <p>{this.state.page_options.hoverMessages.hello}</p> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared your HTML code and its CSS, I'd assume the wrong display of tooltip is happening because of *position: absolute* in your tooltip's CSS.

Comment: Sorry, posted before I was done adding all the details.

Comment: It is still difficult to deduce the reason for this behavior. Could you post the HTML for complete form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main problem is the `left: -295%` property. I'm not sure why you were doing it as a percentage, but if you use a negative pixel value (since you have a hardcoded pixel width), it should work.

**Note:** `<span>` is an inline element, so it cannot contain block-level elements like `<p>`.

Try my sample on [codepen](https://codepen.io/brimer/pen/rXxXza).
I'm not sure what tool you are using, but I converted the placeholders into real HTML attributes and CSS. I also commented out the `inline-block` property of the tooltip class, but it works either way.

**Note:** I used a `calc` function for the `left` property, just to show its relationship to the hardcoded width of 200px.

Comment: Still having issues, but you're right, the `left: -295%` should be in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Brian's suggestion, I changed the `left: -295%` to a pixel value instead. I also made each field have specific `top` attributes as such:

```
<div className="tooltip" style={{ "fontSize": "12px", "fontWeight": "bold" }}> HELLO?
<div className="tooltiptext" style={{ "top": "-102px" }}>
<p>{this.state.page.hello}</p>
</div>
</div>
```